# How to use static method variables in other static methods in Java?

Tags: java, variables, methods, static

I declare and initialize a variable in a static method. How can I use this variable in another static method? I have tried to call the variable by the static method's name.

Comment: Show us what you have tried and then we can go from there.

Comment: You can't use in one method a variable that is declared in another method.

Answer (score 4):

> How do I use a variable that is declared and initialized in one static
>   method and use it in another static method?

**You can't** . Cause the variable's scope belongs only to the method where was declared.

An alternative is making the `variable` as a class variable , then all methods can use this `variable`.

```
public class Test {

private static int variable;

public static void method1(){
   variable++;
}

public static void method2(){
   variable--;
}


}
```

Take care if multiple threads access to these methods.

Comment: We do not know 'global' in java ;)

Comment: @Salandur global as in not-local.

Comment: Not local is also not a very good wording. But the edited version, class variable, is a good one.

Comment: This answer does offer an alternative, but I think you should have also mentioned that you can't access a local variable declared in one method from another method - which is what the OP was looking for.

Comment: @user16547 you got it right, now it seems to be a better answer :D

Answer (score 0):

you can't because if you declaer in one method is this varible local, you must declare as global varibl and initilized in method.

Answer (score 0):

you have to have the variable outside of the method and make it static too.

ex:
    public static int accessMeOutside = 0;

```
public static void methodOne(){
     accessMeOutside = 1;
}

public static void methodTwo(){
    if(accessMeOutside == 1)
       accessMeOutside = 2;
}
```

if you call methodOne, then methodTwo, accessMeOutside will end up correctly being set as 2.